# What's the correct way to deal with tests in a modular system?

Tags: java, testing, junit, java-module

So, I decided to modularize my system and, until getting to tests, everything's been ok. But now, I really don't know the correct way to deal with the test package.

My project is structured like this:

[image]

Basically the thing is that the *EntityDTOConverter* is an utility class that converts an entity to a DTO and vice versa through reflection, using the [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) library.

Now my module-info.java looks like this:

```
module com.vet.clinic.core.app {
  requires com.vet.clinic.core.domain;

  requires typetools;
  requires modelmapper;
  requires jakarta.el;
  requires spring.context;
  requires org.mapstruct.processor;

  exports com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter;
  exports com.vet.clinic.core.app.dto;
}
```

If I run as is, I get the following error:

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Test set: com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.019
>   s <<< FAILURE! - in
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest  Time
>   elapsed: 0.018 s  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public
>   static void
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest.once()
>   accessible: module com.vet.clinic.core.app does not "opens
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter" to unnamed module @20f5239f

Now if I add the following line to the module-info.java:

```
opens com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter;
```

Then the above error is gone, but then I get:

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Test set: com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.163
>   s <<< FAILURE! - in
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest
>   givenDTO_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToBaseEntity  Time elapsed:
>   0.063 s  <<< ERROR! org.modelmapper.MappingException:  ModelMapper mapping errors:
>
> 1) Error mapping com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockBaseEntityDTO to
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockBaseEntity
>
> 1 error   at
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app@0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest.givenDTO_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToBaseEntity(EntityDTOConverterTest.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to
>   make public void
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockBaseEntity.setName(java.lang.String)
>   accessible: module com.vet.clinic.core.app does not "exports
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto" to module modelmapper   at
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app@0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest.givenDTO_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToBaseEntity(EntityDTOConverterTest.java:58)
>
> givenBaseEntity_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToDTO  Time elapsed:
>   0.003 s  <<< ERROR! org.modelmapper.MappingException:  ModelMapper mapping errors:
>
> 1) Error mapping com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockBaseEntity to
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockBaseEntityDTO
>
> 1 error   at
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app@0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest.givenBaseEntity_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToDTO(EntityDTOConverterTest.java:45)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to
>   make public void
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockBaseEntityDTO.setName(java.lang.String)
>   accessible: module com.vet.clinic.core.app does not "exports
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto" to module modelmapper   at
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app@0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest.givenBaseEntity_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToDTO(EntityDTOConverterTest.java:45)
>
> givenListAudibleDTO_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToListBaseEntity 
>   Time elapsed: 0.029 s  <<< ERROR! org.modelmapper.MappingException: 
>   ModelMapper mapping errors:
>
> 1) Error mapping
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockAudibleBaseEntityDTO to
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockBaseEntity
>
> 1 error   at
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app@0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest.givenListAudibleDTO_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToListBaseEntity(EntityDTOConverterTest.java:88)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to
>   make public void
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockBaseEntity.setName(java.lang.String)
>   accessible: module com.vet.clinic.core.app does not "exports
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto" to module modelmapper   at
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app@0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest.givenListAudibleDTO_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToListBaseEntity(EntityDTOConverterTest.java:88)
>
> givenListBaseEntity_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToListAudibleDTO 
>   Time elapsed: 0.007 s  <<< ERROR! org.modelmapper.MappingException: 
>   ModelMapper mapping errors:
>
> 1) Error mapping com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockBaseEntity to
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockAudibleBaseEntityDTO
>
> 1 error   at
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app@0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest.givenListBaseEntity_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToListAudibleDTO(EntityDTOConverterTest.java:72)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to
>   make public void
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto.MockBaseEntityDTO.setName(java.lang.String)
>   accessible: module com.vet.clinic.core.app does not "exports
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto" to module modelmapper   at
>   com.vet.clinic.core.app@0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.vet.clinic.core.app.converter.EntityDTOConverterTest.givenListBaseEntity_whenConvertIsCalled_thenConvertToListAudibleDTO(EntityDTOConverterTest.java:72)

Now I can't do the suggested fix ("exports com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto" to module modelmapper), since this package is only present in the test scope and is not visible for the module-info.java.

By checking some other related questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110023/how-do-you-organize-tests-in-a-modular-java-project), I then tried to add a module-info.java into src/test/java. Despite the fact my IDE (intelliJ ultimate) shows an error saying 'module-info.java already exists in the module', the code can be run.

By adding a module-info.java as simple as that:

```
module core.app.test {
  requires com.vet.clinic.core.domain;
  requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
  exports com.vet.clinic.core.app.mock.dto to modelmapper;
}
```

...I then start to get the following:

> [ERROR] module java.persistence reads package
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime from both org.codehaus.groovy.xml and
>   org.codehaus.groovy [ERROR] module java.persistence reads package
>   groovy.xml from both org.codehaus.groovy.xml and org.codehaus.groovy
>   [ERROR] module java.persistence reads package groovy.util from both
>   org.codehaus.groovy.xml and org.codehaus.groovy [ERROR] module
>   java.persistence reads package org.codehaus.groovy.runtime from both
>   org.codehaus.groovy.xml and org.codehaus.groovy.nio [ERROR] module
>   java.persistence reads package org.codehaus.groovy.runtime from both
>   org.codehaus.groovy.xml and org.codehaus.groovy.sql [ERROR] module
>   java.persistence reads package org.json from both android.json and
>   jsonassert [ERROR] module java.persistence reads package
>   org.codehaus.groovy.transform from both org.codehaus.groovy and
>   org.codehaus.groovy.test [ERROR] module java.persistence reads package
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime from both org.codehaus.groovy.xml and
>   org.codehaus.groovy.test [ERROR] module java.persistence reads package
>   groovy.util from both org.codehaus.groovy.xml and
>   org.codehaus.groovy.test [ERROR] module java.persistence reads package
>   groovy.transform from both org.codehaus.groovy and
>   org.codehaus.groovy.test [ERROR] module java.persistence reads package
>   groovy.lang from both org.codehaus.groovy and org.codehaus.groovy.test

These 11 errors happen multiple times with different modules, not only with java.persistence.

I know this error has to do with automatic modules, but to be honest I have no clue which direction I have to go from here. Any tips?

Comment: Few links that might be useful - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58979522/production-code-test-module-info-unpossible/58990250#58990250), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069098/how-do-i-open-packages-and-require-dependencies-on-test-scope-modules-only-for-j/54070517#54070517) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554304/jdk-11-junit-5-jigsaw-junit-fails-to-run-tests-for-module-info/52578688#52578688).